# TextView shows number instead of character

Tags: android, textview

I want to print **ŒHI 5¹** in my TextView. So I have simply written :

```
tv.setText("Welcome to " + R.string.app_name)
```

where  **R.string.app_name** is `<string name="app_name"><b>ŒHI 5¹</b></string>`

But the strange thing is **textview is showing a number**

The number is: **2131230755**

I have no idea why this is happening.Please help.

Comment: use  getResources().getString() for get actual string not its id

Comment: your reputation suggests this question was a troll one or are you trying to delete a question based on negative votes ?

Comment: Yes definitely it was a troll for me.Sometime silly  mistakes happen due to excessive work pressure.

Comment: @kgandroid indeed indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `getString(R.string.app_name)`

or

```
getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
```

`R.string.app_name` is just a long number genereted to identify that resource. The result of string + long is just that long concatenated to that string. so you need to get the string corresponding to that identifier.

Actually every resource (layout, drawable, array, string) gets an identifier, these are put in the R file. layout identifiers are kept together in an inner class called layout, strings in string and so on.

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
getString(R.string.app_name);
```

or if you are not in an activity then

```
mContext.getResource().getString(R.string.app_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call direct **[R.string](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html)** for your requirement .

Pass `getResource().getString`

> Returns the string value associated with a particular resource ID

Finally

```
getResource().getString(R.string.your_string);
```